# retrieve sql data records in columns instead of rows

Tags: mysql, selector

How can I do a SELECT statement and have it returned the data incolumns instead of rows?

FROM

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | number |
+----+-------+--------+
|  0 | test  |     11 |
|  1 | test2 |     12 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

TO

```
+----+------+--------+----+-------+--------+
| id | name | number | id | name  | number |
+----+------+--------+----+-------+--------+
|  0 | test |     11 |  1 | test2 |     12 |
+----+------+--------+----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Reformatting the question would make it easier to answer - I can't decipher your from / to.

Comment: you should rethink your algorithm, because its not scalable solution. and you really do not achieve anything better than normal select with loop.

Comment: Dobiatowski, I am left with no choice because I am trying to feed the data into a huge datagrid which is in the structure I'm asking the data for. So by retrieving the data like this from sql i can easily feed it to my datagrid.

More info on my goal here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249771/feeding-dynamic-xml-data-to-dynamic-advanced-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pobably you are searching this function:

```
mysql> SELECT student_name,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(test_score)
    ->     FROM student
    ->     GROUP BY student_name;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: fantastic! using group_concat i will actually be able to do what I want. thank you!

Comment: i'm glad :) ask if you want more info.

Comment: This is great thanks again. One minor issue with it though is I read in the docs it would ignore and not display null values with GROUP_CONCAT, are you aware a way to prevent this behavior to null values are shown?

Comment: So what you want to have instead of `NULL` values? empty string? - something like `1,2,3,,4,,5,6,,,7` ?

Answer (score 2):

Look up 'pivot table' in the help files for your database engine.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that in SQL - I'm not even sure that any decent DBMS would allow such a thing!

Comment: @Mike but with MySQL you can only emulate the pivot. EDIT: uhmm, Mike disappeared.